# how to iterate parent to child objects and pushed into an array javascript (vuejs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, vue.js

I have json data like this.

```
    var obj= {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "parent",
            "path": "/",
            "category": "folder",
            "fid":"6"
            "children": [
              {
              //some values
              },
              {
              //some other values
              }
            ]
        }
```

how to iterate and push it into an new array.

**type declaration**

```
getEntry: Array<Object> = []
```

**pushing into an array method**

```
get addedEntry() {
  let files = [] 
  this.getEntry = files.push(this.obj)
}
```

But, i am getting type error. How to push this object into an array or make it array.?

Answer (score 1):

The `push` method returns a Number representing the new value of the array. That's why you are getting a TypeError (you are assigning a Number to an Array of Objects).

You should do the following instead.

```js
get addedEntry() {
  let files = []
  files.push(this.obj)
  this.getEntry = files
}
```

Here's the [docs entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for the `push` method in JavaScript.